# Pre-Selecting a value for a dropdownbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

As the title says really

```
<td><%= Html.DropDownList("Weight", Model.Weightddl.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.Name, Value = x.Id.ToString() }))%></td>
```

Here is my line of code. I have the value Model.Weight which I want to have preselected on the load... How can I set it as the selected value?

thanks

Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the [`Selected` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlistitem.selected.aspx), like this:

```
<td><%= Html.DropDownList("Weight", 
             Model.Weightddl.Select(x => new SelectListItem { 
                 Text = x.Name, 
                 Value = x.Id.ToString(),
                 Selected = (x.Id == Model.Weight)
             }))%></td>
```

Comment: thats a boolean and im not cycling through all the values in the Ienumerable that is Model.Weightddl

Comment: @Steve: See my example.  Alternatively, use the `SelectList` constructor.